# JQuery Mobile IPad: Clicking on inks on higher z-index div causes clicks on underlying content as well

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, mobile, z-index

I created a drop down menu bar for my jquery mobile website which uses higher z-indices to display navigation links. Everything was working fine until I hit this roadblock. This happens only on the ipad. When I have jquery mobile styled checkboxes on the page and I scroll the page. After that, clicking on a drop down menu bar actually causes a click on the checkbox which was actually hidden below that menu item. Anyone encountered a problem like that? What different things can I try out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should include your HTML/CSS so people can understand the stacking context.

Comment: there is too much of stuff going on. I don't know what to put in here.

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle or something so people can actually see it and play with it.

Comment: Turns out it is not show much about the css and js. It's related to the way things work on IOS devices. After scrolling, elements with fixed and absolute positioning don't work so well. Still researching more on this.

Comment: Yes.  Fixed positioning is a big problem with iOS browsers and actually differs significantly between iOS operating system versions.  There are some jQuery plug-ins out ther like iScroll that try to approximate fixed positioning.